# Django: Value being set to None after Object.get

Tags: python, django, modelform

Ok so this question stems from another one that I posted ([Old Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35328931/django-attribute-error-on-custom-save/35329102#35329102)). Essentially I have a view that is trying to assign a value to a `ForeignKey` of a newly created object `new_protocol`. The problem is that for some reason that value is being set to `none`.

What I don't understand is that at the beginning of the view I call the `get_object_or_404`method so there is not reason for that to be set to `none`. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

The `view.py`

```
def add_protocol(request,  study_slug):
    study = get_object_or_404(Study, slug=study_slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_protocol = AddProtocol(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if new_protocol.is_valid():
            new_protocol.save(commit=False)
            new_protocol.study = study
            new_protocol.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('studies:studydetails', args=(study.slug,)))
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Something is messed up')
    else:
        new_protocol = AddProtocol()
        return render(request, 'studies/addprotocol.html', {'new_protocol': new_protocol, 'study': study})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `AddProtocol` is the ModelForm (wouldn't it be better to name it `AddProtocolForm`?), then

```
# ...
# I renamed new_protocol to new_protocol_form here
new_protocol_form = AddProtocol(request.POST, request.FILES)
if new_protocol_form.is_valid():
    # save() method of form returns instance
    new_protocol = new_protocol_form.save(commit=False)
    # assigning related field
    new_protocol.study = study
    new_protocol.save()
# ...
```

[save() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

In your code you assigned `study` to form (not model), so model's `study` got value `None`.

Comment: Man I knew that too. I don't know why I tried to do it the other way. Thank you for the second pair of eyes.